# Laravel - restrict query through relations?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've been hitting my head against the wall with this, so I need a bit of help. I'm using Laravel 4.2.4. I have two models, Event and EventDate.

```php
// Event has id, name
class Event extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'events';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function eventdates()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\EventDate', 'event_id', 'id');
    }
}

// EventDate has id, event_id, start_date, end_date
class EventDate extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'eventdates';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Now I'm trying to get Events between a certain start and end date. So according to the docs, I should be able to do:

```php
\Event::with('eventdates')->where('start_date', '>=', '2014-01-01')->where('end_date', '<=', '2014-02-01')->get();
```

But all that does is throw an `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown Column  'eventdates.start_date' in 'where clause'`.

I've also tried using Closures (if using the repository pattern) such as:

```php
return $this->model->with(['eventdates' => function($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
    $query->where('start_date', '<=', $endDate->format('Y-m-d'));
    $query->where('end_date', '>=', $startDate->format('Y-m-d'));
}]);
```

This feels like a really dumb error, but I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$events = \Event::with(array('eventdates' => function($query){
    // Querying in the eventdates table
    $query->where('start_date', '>=', '2014-01-01')
          ->where('end_date', '<=', '2014-02-01');
}))->get();
```

It's because `start_date` and `end_date` fields are available in the `eventdates` table.

Comment: Doing that returns the full dataset. I've got the profiler open, and it shows:

`select * from eventdates where eventdates.event_id in (ALL THE EVENT IDS) and start_date >= '2014-01-01' and end_date <= '2014-02-01'`

But that's not the actual query being run. Or perhaps it is, but Laravel isn't giving me the correct set back. If I then do `echo $events->count()`, it gives me the total number of results. Running that query right on the DB returns the correct results, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I can more or less answer this question. I had better success using whereHas:

```php
return $this->model->whereHas('eventdates', function($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
    $query->where('start_date', '<=', $endDate->format('Y-m-d'));
    $query->where('end_date', '>=', $startDate->format('Y-m-d'));
})
->with('eventdates');
```

Thanks, all.